# OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener not registering change in preference

Tags: android, listener, listpreference

I'm working on listpreferences and I have implemented the OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener to change the text on a textview based on which item is selected on the listpreference. However it doesn't register any changes and I have run out of ideas so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
public class pref extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String keys = null;
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    pref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);


    keys = pref.getString("listPref1", "");
    if (keys == "ON")
    {
        text.setText("ON");
    }
    else if (keys == "OFF")
    {
        text.setText("OFF");
    }
    else{
        text.setText("Choose One");
    }
}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {
    //What code to I put in here to have the listener register the change
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like it should work: you can try logging out to ensure its doing what it should. Move all the conditional code into the listener.

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {
    android.util.Log.v("PREFERENCE CHANGE", "[" + key + "]");
    if ("listPref1".equals(key)) {
        String keys = pref.getString("listPref1", "");
        if (keys == "ON") {
            text.setText("ON");
        } else if (keys == "OFF") {
            text.setText("OFF");
        } else {
            text.setText("Choose One");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your code but its still not working, When I first ran the app the textview was empty but when I changed the selected item, the textview was set to "Choose One" but it's stuck on this and doesn't change regardless of the item selected

Comment: Do this: `android.util.Log.v("PREFERENCE CHANGE VALUES", "["+keys+"]");` after you do the `pref.getString("listPref1", "");` and see what it reports (AND VERIFY THAT **listPref1** is the correct preference key to use).

Comment: I should be checking for the key of the items in the listpreference with key "listpref1".

Comment: Oh, well, then change the call to `String keys = pref.getString("listpref1","");`. The preference infrastructure is case sensitive.

Comment: no, the case thing was my error. What I'm saying is My key for my list preference is listpref1, it has two items with keys ON and OFF. I want have something happen when the user selects ON and another when he selects OFF. Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: You should probably use `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener` (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html . You can simply register it to listen to just your preference (so `((Preference) findPreference(getString("listpref1"))).setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);`) and then implement `public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue)` which will get called if they change anything.

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks good for registering to hear preference changes, you need to put some code in your `onSharedPreferenceChanged` method to process the preferences as they are changed. Remember that you will get called back when *any* preference changes, so you need to do some filtering in the method to make sure it's what you're interested in.

Could be something as simple as:

```
if(key.equals("listPref1"))
   text.setText("ON"); // Need to make text a class variable
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your help, I've sorted most of it out now here is the code

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    if (prefs.getString("listPref1", "").equals("OFF")) {
        text.setText("goodbye");
    } else if (prefs.getString("listPref1", "").equals("ON")) {
        text.setText("hello");
    }

    prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    if (prefs.getString("listPref1", "").equals("OFF")) {
        text.setText("goodbye");
    } else if (prefs.getString("listPref1", "").equals("ON")) {
        text.setText("hello");
    }
}
```

}

As you can see I have to repeat the if/else statement, if I put it only in the listener nothing gets until a change is made and for if it's only outside the listener it only gets read when the app is first run and changes are not registered.

Isn't there a code to get the listener to notify a change has been made and the code gets re-run?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any code to actually update your SharedPreferences. The listener will only be triggered when your `pref` object is edited. Example...

```
pref.edit().putString("listPref1", "ONE").commit();
```