# How to listen to listPreference, to change screen orientation?

Tags: sharedpreferences, screen-orientation, preferenceactivity, listpreference

I have a PreferenceActivity in which I would like to have the option to change/lock the screen orientation.

The orientation should lock **only** the Main Activity screen orientation

I not sure were and how I should call the change listener.
On the onCreate and onResume of the Main Activity seems right but I can't get it to work.

**settings.xml**

```
   <ListPreference     android:title="Screen orientation"
    android:summary="current: %s"
    android:key="rotation"
    android:defaultValue="1"
    android:entries="@array/listArray"
    android:entryValues="@array/listValues" />
```

**array.xml**

```
<resources>
<string-array name="listArray">
    <item>Auto rotate</item>
    <item>Portrait</item>
    <item>Landscape</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="listValues">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</string-array>
```

**The Preference Activity**

```
public class MyPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
}

public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment  {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }

}
```

Links I already looked

[How to create a Listener to Preferences changes in Preferences activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38109685/how-to-create-a-listener-to-preferences-changes-in-preferences-activity)

[Adding listeners to individual ListPreference items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031915/adding-listeners-to-individual-listpreference-items)

[How to listen for preference changes within a PreferenceFragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596250/how-to-listen-for-preference-changes-within-a-preferencefragment)

[OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener not registering change in preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922781/onsharedpreferencechangelistener-not-registering-change-in-preference)

http://envyandroid.com/android-detect-preference-changes/

Answer (score 1):

After a long time but it's helpful for other developers. You need to implement  `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener` to listen dialog of radio buttons or `enteries` in Dialog. Then `onPreferenceChange` param `newValue` give select ration button value.

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat(), Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)
        
        val modePrefs :ListPreference = findPreference("rotation")!!
        modePrefs.onPreferenceChangeListener = this
    }
    override fun onPreferenceChange(preference: Preference?, newValue: Any?): Boolean {
        if ()
        return true
    }
}
```